# Why is C++ constructor aware of member variable values that are not yet assigned?

Tags: c++, constructor

I was messing around with a very basic class and found something peculiar.

The class contains a private member variable, a setter for the member, and a constructor that prints out the private member.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << privateMember << '\n';
    }
    void setPrivateMember(int x) {
        privateMember = x;
    }
 private:
    int privateMember;
};
```

Since my constructor takes no arguments, and there being no way to set Base::privateMember without using the public setter function, I expected it to print out garbage every time I initialized a new Base object. However, that is not the case.

In the main() I initialize a Base object. Like so:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Base b;

    b.setPrivateMember(10);

    return 0;
}
// Prints 10
```

**The thing that I do understand is why the program prints 10**.

I was under the impression that the constructor would be called without Base::privateMember being initialized, printing out garbage, but that is not the case.

So I tested other methods of initialization below:

If I create the object and then don't set the variable, it prints out garbage as expected. Like so:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Base b;

    return 0;
}
// Prints garbage
```

If I allocate memory on the heap, it also prints garbage as expected, whether I use the setter or not. Like so:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Base *b = new Base();

    // same result whether this line exists or not
    b->setPrivateMember(10);

    return 0;
}
// Prints garbage
```

Can anyone explain why this behavior is happening?

Comment: Maybe your compiler optimizes this so that the value gets hardcoded into the class?

Comment: Arguing about garbage is not productive. Garbage in, garbage out. You can't predict the value

Comment: Fair enough I suppose :)

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is ... wait for it ... *Undefined*!

Comment: A duplicate of a duplicate?

Comment: 0 is a reasonable garbage.